# KafkaController required a bean of type 'org.springframework.kafka.requestreply.ReplyingKafkaTemplate' that could not be found?

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am trying to use the `RepliyngKafkaTemplate` like I managed to use the `KafkaTemplate` in a REST controller.

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    private ReplyingKafkaTemplate<Object, KafkaExampleRecord, KafkaExampleRecord> replyingTemplate;

    @PostMapping("/test/request")
    public void requestReply(@RequestBody KafkaExampleRecord record) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException, TimeoutException {
        ProducerRecord<Object, KafkaExampleRecord> producerRecord = new ProducerRecord<>("mytopic", record);
        RequestReplyFuture<Object, KafkaExampleRecord, KafkaExampleRecord> replyFuture = replyingTemplate.sendAndReceive(producerRecord);

        SendResult<Object, KafkaExampleRecord> sendResult = replyFuture.getSendFuture().get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        ConsumerRecord<Object, KafkaExampleRecord> consumerRecord = replyFuture.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

However I am getting the following exception.

```
Field replyingTemplate in com.blah.KafkaController required a bean of type 'org.springframework.kafka.requestreply.ReplyingKafkaTemplate' that could not be found.
```

I enabled auto configuration like this.

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConfig {

}
```

All Kafka settings are in my `application.yml`.

What else do I need? Do I really have to define beans? Seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I really have to define beans? Seems unnecessary.

Yes, you have to declare a beans for the replying template (including the reply container); Spring Boot only auto configures a simple `KafkaTemplate`.

Answer (score 2):

Can you check, whether you are scanning the basePackages correctly. Sometimes, you may end-up with this issue, if you not scanning the packages correctly, and I have experienced this many times in the Spring Boot application.

```
@ComponentScan(
        basePackages = {
                "x.x.x.x"
        }
)
```

Comment: I added `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.blah")` to my application but I am getting same exception.

Comment: Can you register your Bean something like this, in your KafkaConfig.    

@Bean //register and configure replying kafka template
    public ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, Object, Object> replyingTemplate(
            ProducerFactory<String, Object> pf,
            ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, Object> repliesContainer) {
        return new ReplyingKafkaTemplate<>(pf, repliesContainer);
    }

You can refer https://www.techgalery.com/2021/08/spring-kafka-how-to-use.html