# KafkaReplyTemplate throws: a KafkaTemplate is required to support replies?

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

This is a follow up to [KafkaController required a bean of type 'org.springframework.kafka.requestreply.ReplyingKafkaTemplate' that could not be found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72769901/kafkacontroller-required-a-bean-of-type-org-springframework-kafka-requestreply).

Now I am getting `java.lang.IllegalStateException: a KafkaTemplate is required to support replies`. My setup now looks like this.

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConfig {
    @Bean
    public ReplyingKafkaTemplate<Object, KafkaExampleRecord, KafkaExampleRecord> replyingKafkaTemplate(ProducerFactory<Object, KafkaExampleRecord> producerFactory,
                                                                                                       ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<Object, KafkaExampleRecord> rc) {
        return new ReplyingKafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory, rc);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<Object, KafkaExampleRecord> repliesContainer(
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, KafkaExampleRecord> containerFactory) {

        ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<Object, KafkaExampleRecord> rc =
                containerFactory.createContainer("mytopic");
        rc.setAutoStartup(false);
        return rc;
    }
}
```

Im my REST controller I now have this.

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<Object, KafkaExampleRecord> template;

    @Autowired
    private ReplyingKafkaTemplate<Object, KafkaExampleRecord, KafkaExampleRecord> replyingTemplate;

    @PostMapping("/test/produce")
    public void produceToTopic(@RequestBody KafkaExampleRecord record) {
        ListenableFuture<SendResult<Object, KafkaExampleRecord>> future = template.send("mytopic", record);
    }

    @PostMapping("/test/request")
    public void requestReply(@RequestBody KafkaExampleRecord record) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException, TimeoutException {
        ProducerRecord<Object, KafkaExampleRecord> producerRecord = new ProducerRecord<>("mytopic", record);
        RequestReplyFuture<Object, KafkaExampleRecord, KafkaExampleRecord> replyFuture = replyingTemplate.sendAndReceive(producerRecord);

        SendResult<Object, KafkaExampleRecord> sendResult = replyFuture.getSendFuture().get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  
}
```

The exception is thrown at `SpringApplication.run(MyClass.class, args)`.

From https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#replying-template and https://www.techgalery.com/2021/08/spring-kafka-how-to-use.html it looks like I have everything I need now. What is still missing?

Answer (score 0):

See documentation about server side receive-n-reply semantics: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#annotation-send-to

> In order to support `@SendTo`, the listener container factory must be provided with a `KafkaTemplate` (in its `replyTemplate` property), which is used to send the reply.

Comment: Since the `RKT` is an extension of `KafkaTemplate`, Boot will no longer configure a default one (which it normally injects into the container factory). You will need to define a `KafkaTemplate<Object, Object>` bean as well as the `RKT`, and Boot will wire it in.

Answer (score 0):

Since the replyingKafkaTemplate is an extension of KafkaTemplate, Boot will no longer configure a default one . You will need to define a separate KafkaTemplate<Object, Object> bean along with replyingKafkaTemplate .Please look into my another question where I maintain both kafkatemplate and replyingKafkaTemplate  separately along with listener factory with setReplyTemplate.

[ExecutionException:Due to: org.springframework.kafka.requestreply.KafkaReplyTimeoutException: Reply timed out using ReplyingKafkaTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73657031/executionexceptiondue-to-org-springframework-kafka-requestreply-kafkareplytime/73736521?noredirect=1#comment130278569_73736521)

Comment: This was the solution but it as actually Gary's answer (see comment above). Now what? :)